# How to import class using fully qualified name?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

create file `test1.scala` with following code:

```
package test
import java.io.FileInputStream
object Foo
```

create another file `test2.scala` with following code:

```
package test.java
object Bar
```

Now compile as `scalac test1.scala test2.scala`:

We get the error:

```
test.scala:2: error: object io is not a member of package test.java
import java.io.FileInputStream
            ^
one error found
```

I think the error is because Scala thinks that `java` above refers to package `test.java`. How to resolve this problem apart from renaming the package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import _root_.java.io.FileInputStream
```

Or to simplify things, you might use an alias:

```
import _root_.java.{io => jio}
import jio.FileInputStream
```